# is there any limit to how much time the server can process?

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, runtime, client-server

I have the following file which *process a single XML* file and pushes it into the Database as a row. It *works perfectly* for single files.

Now i wanted to put *ALL files in the directory* like this into the database and hence wrote a script to go over the directory and push all the files in it one by one. And ***YES it did work, but it stopped after processing XX (variable) amount of files***

I though may be something wrong with my XML file, so decided to just have SINGLE XML file (which was perfectly processed earlier) in the directory and just loop over it, inserting it hundreds of time, so that i could confirm its a problem with my files. But guess what happened?

**After processing XX(variable) amount of files, the processing stops**. In my below example, it stopped at 110 (counter val), 111, 99 etc after repeated attempts. Where it should have processed 1000 files.

```
<?php
include_once '../includeTop.php';

header ( 'Content-type: text/xml' );

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
$dir = "../../newHotelFiles";
$file = NULL;
$fileName = "noFileName";

$processed = 0;
util::writeToLog ( $dir . '/progressData.tmp', "Files processed: $processed" );
try {

    echo XMLInterface::openTag ( "start" );
    for($counter = 0; $counter < 1000; $counter ++) {
        $dirHandle = opendir ( '../../newHotelFiles' );
        while ( false !== ($file = readdir ( $dirHandle )) ) {
            //process my files codes

                $processed ++;
                util::writeToLog ( $dir . '/progressData.tmp', "Files processed: $processed" );


            }

        }

    //util::writeToLog($dir.'/progressData.tmp', "Done ".$counter);
    }
    echo XMLInterface::closeTag ( "start" );
    exit ();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo XMLInterface::failure ( "Error occured. Written to the log file - $file.log" );
    util::writeToLog ( "../../newHotelFiles/$fileName.log", ExceptionHandler::error_msg ( $e ) );
    exit ();
}

?>
```

What is the problem? Is it the script (which i doubt as it works when the for loop is not there) or *is there any serverside limit i donot know about*

Comment: Not really related, but why are you using PHP to do this? PHP was intended as a templating language, not a programming language. Export this to a separate script so your webserver doesn't take up too much processing (use Python or something).

Comment: @tjameson With all due respect, intention doesn't figure into this much, or so I figure. `PHP`, although far from my favourite language personally, is Turing-complete and is well suited to do what OP seems to be doing with it. Also, just as Perl to name one, you can invoke it on command line, independent of Apache, HTTP, CGI etc.

Comment: @footy Did you know that you can invoke `PHP` from command-line, as an interpreter? That will most likely eliminate the cause for your timeout errors, and if everything else is fine with your code and you don't need part of the API that has to do with HTTP, CGI or Apache (sorry, repeating myself), then you invariably are better off. Use 'php -f /path/to/file.php`. Not all PHP distributions come with the command line interpreter though, but it's handy indeed.

Comment: Just because you can use a nail clipper to nail file to sand a 2x4 doesn't mean it's the best tool for the job. Using a template language to perform heavy tasks on a webserver is not the correct usage of the webserver, and could cause an accidental DoS, especially for something like this where the task is relatively large. True, Apache puts things in separate threads, but it's still under the same parent process.

Comment: I never said it's the correct usage on a webserver, in fact most of my argument had to do with invoking it instead on the command line. Let it be noted that I agree with you on the fact that using a webserver as a generic scripting host is most often a lousy idea. But you need to take it easy on "template language" thing - first of all, `PHP` has outgrown that label, and second, I would like to hear from you what makes a template language, and why are Perl, Python and Javascript to name a few not de facto templating languages? Is it because `PHP` uses XML processing instructions?

Comment: @amn I did this in php as my client wanted every thing in php. I will look into how to invoke the process through command line. Thanks

Comment: @footy You won't violate your clients requirements by invoking the command line PHP interpreter. In fact, you'll be meeting their requirements in even stricter and thus more professional manner, because you'll throw away a thing that is not needed and is thus a potential liability, source of errors, and is an unnecessary dependency. Unless they ask for the code to be run on a web server (for a very good reason I hope) which I don't think they would. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. All of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a max execution time limit in php called set_time_limit(); (along others)

```
        set_time_limit(0); // sets to unlimited
```

Comment: I applaud your generosity with providing a correct answer (not being sarcastic) but I have this (unfounded?) fear that you just let @footy shoot themselves in the foot with a shotgun of the PHP+Apache brand :/ I am referring to the fact correctly pointed out in the comments that involving a (production) web server to simply process a file and store data in a database is a door to many bad a place.

Answer (score 1):

The script may be aborting because of a time limit.  Try modifying the [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).